# *ngFor object comparison using '==='

Tags: angular, typescript, object, comparison, ngfor

Going through the Angular tutorial (Tour of Heroes), I've stumbled upon a comparison between two objects. Since this is not a common practice I've tried multiple comparisons inside the class and all returned `false`, except if the compared are `hero[0]` and `selectedHero`, the returned value is `true`, assuming we assigned `selectedHero` with `hero[0]`.

Tour of Heores part of code where comparison occurs: [Link to StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lmgdaavbdmbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.html)

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Why is this comparison returning true? What exactly is being compared here? I haven't found any explanation yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`===` is checking the value (if the subject is a number or a boolean), the type and the object reference.
If you create 2 objects with identical attributes like the following, it will return false :

```
let a = { test: 'test' };
let b = { test: 'test' };
console.log(a === b); // gives false
```

because it's not the same reference.
So in your case, `selectedHero === hero` will be true if your 2 objects has the same reference.

**EDIT :**

Another precision is that you can copy object reference in another :

```
let a = { test: 'test' };
let b = a;
console.log(a === b); // gives true
```

and then if you change attribute of one the reference, it will change for both :

```
let a = { test: 'test' };
let b = a;
a.test = 'foo';
console.log(b.test) // gives foo
```

Comment: Okay, I see it now in the Javascript documentation. Clears it up a bit. So basically the reference points to the objects location in memory?

Comment: Yes, you have some exemples in this following [link](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on li elemnt `onSelect` is executed and set the variable `selectedHero` with the elemnt hero from heroes array,heroes containe objects so the assaignment is just set selectedHero to be refrence to the current elemnt(hero) and when we try to comapre( == or ===) object the compare if the point to the same refrence or not

```
let a = {};
let b = {};
let c = a;

console.log(a === b); // false 
console.log(a === c); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

=== on an Object checks the address of the object and not the value. If you want more information you can look up how pointers work.

But basically if (hero === selectedHero) returns true then they point to the same memory address. Therefore, if you change the value of selectedHero, it will also have change the value of hero[0].